# Cant Get a result form random.shuffle in python

Tags: python

I have never had this problem before but when i try and shuffle a list i get a return of 'None'

```
import random
c=[1,4,67,3]
c=random.shuffle(c)
print c
```

The print statement returns 'None' and i dont know why, I have looked around for an answer to this problem but there doesent seem to be anything. I hope i am not making an obvious mistake.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `random.shuffle` function sorts the list in-place, and to avoid causing confusion on that point, it doesn't return the shuffled list.  Try just:

```
 random.shuffle(c)
 print(c)
```

This is a nice bit of API design, I think - it means that if you misunderstand what `random.shuffle` is doing, then you'll get a obvious problem immediately, rather than a more subtle bug that's difficult to track down later on...

Answer (score 3):

Remember that `random.shuffle()` shuffles in-place. So it updates the object named “c”. But then you rebind “c” with `None`, the output of the function, and the list gets lost.

Answer (score 1):

From the [doc](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.shuffle) :

> Shuffle the sequence x in place.

So

```
import random
c=[1,4,67,3]
random.shuffle(c)
print c
```

works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

import random
c=[1,4,67,3]
random.shuffle(c)
print c